# Add timestamp watermark to PhantomJS images

Tags: phantomjs, watermark

How can I add watermarks on Phantomjs images?

Somewhat like this:
[image]

Can `page.evaluate` help me here?

Any injection or while rendering should not affect the actual look of the webpage. This stamp should only overlay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got it.

Created a new html element which is required, from DOM method and then injected this while rendering the HTML by `page.evaluate`.

Comment: Your answer is basically saying the same thing as mine. Do you mind exanding with actual code to warrant the new answer?

Answer (score 5):

The rendering is very high level in PhantomJS. The only way is to inject the watermark as an element (think `position: absolute`) into the DOM through `page.evaluate` and remove it after the screenshot.